# Apache Pig: LIMIT inside FOREACH referencing toplevel field, Scalar has more than one row in the output

Tags: foreach, apache-pig, limit

This question is similar to one asked two years ago, however for some reason, it does not work for me.  Actually this is a combination of two ideas (answered questions) as given in the header.  The example below replicates the accepted solution however it does not work for me:  What is my mistake?  I give a complete self contained working example:

Here is the data:
    cat in_detail.csv

```
grp,val
1,2.1,
1,4.2,
1,6.3
2,6.5
2,1.2
2,4.3
2,3.2

cat in_cnt.csv
grp,cnt
1,2
2,3
```

output expected  (sort order not important):

```
grp,val
1,2.1,
1,4.2,
2,6.5
2,1.2
2,4.3
```

Here is the code: with the error message

```
detail1    = LOAD '/tmp/sD_mvmd/c0nelha/data/in_detail.csv'   using PigStorage(',') as (grp:chararray,num:double);

cnt1       = LOAD  '/tmp/sD_mvmd/c0nelha/data/in_cnt.csv' using     

PigStorage(',') as (grp:chararray,cnt:int);

d_group = GROUP detail1 by (grp);

describe d_group;

--d_group: {group: chararray,detail1: {(grp: chararray,num: double)}}

describe cnt1;

--cnt1: {grp: chararray,cnt: int}

detail2 = JOIN d_group by (group), cnt1 by (grp);

describe detail2;

--detail2: {d_group::group: chararray,d_group::detail1: {(grp: chararray,num: double)},cnt1::grp: chararray,cnt1::cnt: int}

detail3 = FOREACH detail2 {

    mySelection   = LIMIT d_group::detail1 detail2.cnt1::cnt;

    GENERATE mySelection;
}

-- Apache Pig version 0.12.1.2.1.5.0-695 (rexported) compiled Aug 27 2014, 23:56:19

-- Backend error : Scalar has more than one row in the output.

-- 1st : (1,{(1,6.3),(1,4.2),(1,2.1)},1,2), 2nd :(2,{(2,3.2),(2,4.3),(2,1.2),(2,6.5)},2,3)

dump detail3;
```

Comment: Plz add the expected output